# Prevent ships from overlapping in Battleship (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I am trying to prevent ships from overlapping in this Battleship project I am working on but cannot figure out how to prevent them from overlapping in 2d array. I have tried using the includes() method to see if the ship value exists already but does not work. Not really sure how to tackle this problem.

```js
const Gameboard = () => {
  const rows = 10
  const columns = 10
  const board = []
  const missedCoord = []

  console.log(board)
  const getBoard = () => [...board]

  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i += 1) {
    board[i] = []
    for (let j = 0; j < columns; j += 1) {
      board[i][j] = null
    }
  }

  // Need to reduce array amount to a single value
  const cellCount = getBoard().reduce((row, col) => row + col.length, 0)

  const placeShipsHorizontal = (x, y, ship, direction) => {
    const shipsLength = ship.getLength()
    const currentBoard = getBoard()
    if (direction === "horizontal") {
      if (y + shipsLength > columns) {
        console.log("Cannot place ship horizontally, out of bounds.");
        return false;
      }
      // Places ship horizontally
      for (let i = 0; i < shipsLength; i += 1) {
        if (currentBoard.includes(ship)) {
          return false
        }
        board[x][y + i] = ship.name
      }
    }
    return true
  }
  const placeShipsVertical = (x, y, ship, direction) => {
    const shipsLength = ship.getLength()
    const currentBoard = getBoard()
    if (direction === "vertical") {
      if (x + shipsLength > rows) {
        if (board[x][y].includes(null))
          console.log("Cannot place ship vertically, out of bounds.")
        return false
      }
    }
    // Places ship vertically
    for (let i = 0; i < shipsLength; i += 1) {
      if (currentBoard.includes(ship)) {
        return false
      }
      board[x + i][y] = ship.name;
    }
    return true
  }

  function receiveAttack(x, y, ship) {
    // If board has coordinate with ship
    if (board[x][y]) {
      // Send hit to ship
      ship.hit()
      // Mark X where ship has been hit
      board[x][y] = "X"
      console.log(`${ship.name} has been hit!`)
      if (ship.isSunk()) {
        console.log(`${ship.name} has sunk!`)
      }
      return true
    }
    // Push missed coordinates to array
    missedCoord.push(x, y)
    console.log(`Attack missed at coordinates: [${x},${y}]`)
    return false
  }
  return {
    placeShipsVertical,
    placeShipsHorizontal,
    getBoard,
    cellCount,
    receiveAttack
  }
}


const gameboard = Gameboard()

gameboard.placeShipsHorizontal(2, 4, testShip, "horizontal")
gameboard.placeShipsVertical(2, 4, testShip2, "vertical")
```

```js
const createShip = (shipLength, name) => {
  let hits = 0
  let sunk = false

  function getLength() {
    return this.shipLength
  }

  function hit() {
    hits += 1
    return hits
  }

  function isSunk() {
    if (hits >= shipLength) {
      sunk = true
      return sunk
    }
    sunk = false
    return sunk
  }
  return {
    getLength,
    hit,
    isSunk,
    shipLength,
    name,
    hits
  }
}

const testShip = createShip(3, "Boat")
const testShip2 = createShip(5, "Boat 2")
```

```js
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, 'Boat 2', 'Boat', 'Boat', null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, 'Boat 2', null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, 'Boat 2', null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, 'Boat 2', null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, 'Boat 2', null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

Comment: How is this related to TDD?